# change a particular cell in datagridview to be of type combo

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

i am binding a datagridview from custom datatable.  i want a particular datacel to be of combo type. can it be done, if so how?

in the code snippet below, if the key == "somevalue", i want to create a row where the datarow[1] will be of combo type. can it be done?

private void UpdateDataTable(string key, object value)
{

```
if(dt.Rows.Contains(key))
{
    Debug.WriteLine("found row");
    DataRow myrow = dt.Rows.Find( key);
    myrow["Values"]= value;
}
else
{
  dt.LoadDataRow(new object[] { key, value }, true);
}

dt.AcceptChanges();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it. I believe you have to tinker with DataGridViewCell.EditType.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.edittype.aspx